# Can you present data on non-participants?

Tags: ethics, data, privacy

Are you allowed to present data on those who declined to participate in your study?

The following is an excerpt from a study on whiplash-traumas where the authors clearly publish some basic statistics on people who declined to participate [1].

> Emergency departments identified 6952 eligible participants, of which 3851 (55%) agreed to provide follow-up data (figure). People who participated were older (mean age 37 years vs 32 years) and more likely to be female (2133 [55%] of 3851 vs 1435 [42%] 3430) than the patients who did not participate, but not different in whiplash associated disorder grade.

---

[1] Lamb SE, Gates S, Williams M a., Williamson EM, Mt-Isa S, Withers EJ, et al. Emergency department treatments and physiotherapy for acute whiplash: A pragmatic, two-step, randomised controlled trial. Lancet [Internet]. Elsevier Ltd; 2013;381(9866):546–56. Available from: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0140-6736(12)61304-X

Comment: What is your worry here, exactly?

Comment: @vonbrand That it would be unethical to include data on someone who did not want to participate.

Comment: If the only thing reported is the *number* of non-participants, and there is are enough population to making identification of participants/non-participants next to impossible, I don't see a problem.

Comment: @vonbrand: I agree, though in my example the authors also compared the diagnoses of participants with those of non-participants.

Comment: Note that the above study is looking at people who *declined to provide follow-up data*. That says nothing about the basic demographic and diagnostic data the study already had access to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is standard practice. And it is necessary in order to detect selection bias.

The [CONSORT initiative (Consolidated Standards of Reporting Trials)](http://www.consort-statement.org/) provides a [flow chart](http://www.consort-statement.org/consort-statement/flow-diagram) that includes entries for "declined to participate" and dropouts in various follow-ups.

The American Psychological Association, in its [Ethical Principles for Psychologists and Code of Conduct](http://www.apa.org/ethics/code/index.aspx?item=11), section 8.05 "Dispensing with Informed Consent for Research", writes:

> Psychologists may dispense with informed consent only (1) where
>   research would not reasonably be assumed to create distress or harm
>   and involves (a) the study of normal educational practices, curricula,
>   or classroom management methods conducted in educational settings; (b)
>   only anonymous questionnaires, naturalistic observations or archival
>   research for which disclosure of responses would not place
>   participants at risk of criminal or civil liability or damage their
>   financial standing, employability or reputation, and confidentiality
>   is protected; or (c) the study of factors related to job or
>   organization effectiveness conducted in organizational settings for
>   which there is no risk to participants' employability, and
>   confidentiality is protected or (2) where otherwise permitted by law
>   or federal or institutional regulations.

The kind of summary statistics you cite falls squarely under point 1b.

Of course, you *do* need to exercise some caution, in particular to ensure that confidentiality is maintained. Listing the names of non-participants, for instance, would certainly cross the line. As would giving out "too much" information from which one could reasonably deduce the identities of participants or non-participants (if you work with a small, easily identified population, say).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that this is clearly relevant to the study. As long as no personally identifiable data (and just the numbers cited clearly don't qualify as that) I don't see a problem.

In the end, "declined to participate" is an indicator of some self-selection, which could introduce some bias.